# No 'Code Coverage' decorations in SonarQube 5.1+

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I've installed SonarQube 5.1 (and now 5.1.1 as a desperate move) on a Redhat 6 but I can't see any code-coverage decorations in the files itself. I've successfully did en maven-jacoco-sonar-build and I can see everything in Sonarqube (even the code coverage percentages per package/file) but when I view the files itself there are no red/green lines present.

Things I've checked/done so far:

- I'm logged in as administrator
- I did an API call coverage/show?from=1&to=100&key=... and I see the lines, in the resultset, that are covered (the second argument in every element). The data is clearly present in the database.
- I've checked the permissions in "Security", specifically the 'Project Settings' (because I've encountered quite a few google hits with bugs in that area) and "Anyone,..." has the proper permissions to "Browse" en "See Source code"
- When I look at the source code of the page I see clearly a div for the scm/duplication-check/... but there are no for "coverage". It seems like Sonarqube comes up empty when it searches for coverage.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: If you take a look at Nemo (ex. http://nemo.sonarqube.org/component/index?id=org.codehaus.sonar%3Asonar-server%3Asrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fsonar%2Fserver%2Futil%2FSlug.java), you can see the coverage bar on the left (https://www.evernote.com/l/APupDA81i0BN5rfKyQ4q5VQONQKQnmczlLI). So can you check if you don't have JavaScript errors in your browser? (and which browser are you using BTW?)

Comment: I can see the red and green bars in your url. I've tried with FF and Chrome but there is no difference (my whole team can't see the coverage btw). I don't have any errors in my browser when loading the page. That's why I have no idea how to fix this or what the problem is...

Comment: Can you please post (on pastebin.com for instance) the answer of "/api/sources/lines" for one of your files?

Comment: I've copied the output at http://pastebin.com/nnHceCRs . When I check the output from your URL, there is a "utLineHits"tag more to indicate if the row is covered by a test or not. Are there cases when this check fails?

Comment: Can you please stop SQ, delete the 'data/es' folder and restart it?

Comment: Thank you ! That was the solution :-)

Comment: Great! I added this advice as an answer to your question so that you can validate it and therefore make other users benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Elasticsearch cache is corrupted or at least not up-to-date.

To fix this:

- Stop SQ
- Delete the `<install_dir>/data/es` folder
- Restart SQ